# Use of Apache Shiro Session only as a Request-scoped bucket of security data

Tags: session, shiro

I use Shiro in backend RESTful Services. I effectively disabled Session Management because i want our Services to be stateless and authenticate and authorise in every request. 
But now i have the following requirement: during the authentication process that happens in my Realm, i go to an SSO server and retrieve some security context data, that i need them to be available in every Resource endpoint method of the RESTful contract. These data may be used by the end-developer to create proper permission strings to check. The problem is that i don't seem to find a proper place to put these data except from the Session object. My questions are:

1). Is Session object the only viable solution to put these data? I know that i can use some custom structure for this reason, but i would really prefer to be something offered by Shiro and logically close to the Subject so that the end-developer knows that this is "security context data" that we are talking about. On the other hand, i'm happy with not completely enabling and using the complexities of the Session. 
2). In my solution, i execute a SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession() in my doGetAuthenticationInfo method of my Realm implementation. I put the data in this Session. At the end of the Request, in the afterCompletion() implementation of my Filter, i execute these:

```
Subject subject = ThreadContext.unbindSubject(); 
Session session = subject.getSession(false); 
if(session != null) session.stop();
```

So essentially, i am trying to use Session in a Request-scoped approach.

Is this a good workaround? Can i be sure that my data are specific to the subject (which is created and deleted per request)? Do you know of anything else i should consider?